# Checkbox is not updating the property on struts

Tags: jsp, checkbox, struts, struts-1

I have list of samples which has list of tests under it. I am setting the property added to the html:checkbox. When the checkbox is checked the value of added variable is not changing.

```
<logic:iterate id="samples" name="<%=formName%>" property="samples" indexId="sampleIndex"
                       type="Sample">

            <tr>
                <td>
                <span class="itemNumber">
                    <bean:write name="samples" property="accessionNumber"/>
                </span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <bean:write name="samples" property="sampleType"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <ul>
                        <logic:iterate id="tests" name="samples" property="tests" indexId="testIndex"
                                       type="Test">
                            <li class="test-name">
                                <html:hidden name="tests" property="testId" indexed="true"/>
                                <label>
                                    <html:checkbox name="tests" property="added" indexed="true" value="true"/>
                                    <bean:write name="tests" property="testName"/>
                                    <bean:write name="tests" property="added"/>
                                </label>
                            </li>
                        </logic:iterate>
                    </ul>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </logic:iterate>
```

When I access the samples i am getting the unmodified list.

```
dynaForm.get("samples");
```

I set the values to the samples like this:

```
PropertyUtils.setProperty(dynaForm, "samples", possibleSampleList);
```

Can someone help me understand why it is not changing the value of the property "added"

Comment: What a variable are you talking?

Comment: The property of checkbox, which is 'added'

Comment: Post a code where you define a list.

Comment: PropertyUtils.setProperty(dynaForm, "samples", possibleSampleList);

Answer (score 0):

Changing this:

```
<html:checkbox name="tests" property="added" indexed="true" value="true"/>
```

to the following:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="samples[<bean:write name='sampleIndex'/>].tests[<bean:write name='testIndex'/>].added">
```

fixed this.